# Calling HTML forms and CSS on another site

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to HTML/javascript so I apologize if this is a bit abstract, I'm not quite sure how to word the title. I did a bit of research and I understand the same origin policy applies, so assume I have the headers set for anyone to access.

I've always wondered how software like Olark works when integrated into another site. What I mean is they provide a short amount code to copy/paste onto your site, and then you have a wonderful looking styled and interactive form. I guess what's most puzzling to me is that there is seemingly very little HTML but obviously that's how it's generated on the page.

I signed up for the service just to see what the code looks like and here's what they gave me to copy/paste onto my site (with my information removed)

```
<!-- begin olark code -->
<script data-cfasync="false" type='text/javascript'>/*<![CDATA[*/window.olark||(function(c){var f=window,d=document,l=f.location.protocol=="https:"?"https:":"http:",z=c.name,r="load";var nt=function(){
f[z]=function(){
(a.s=a.s||[]).push(arguments)};var a=f[z]._={
},q=c.methods.length;while(q--){(function(n){f[z][n]=function(){
f[z]("call",n,arguments)}})(c.methods[q])}a.l=c.loader;a.i=nt;a.p={
0:+new Date};a.P=function(u){
a.p[u]=new Date-a.p[0]};function s(){
a.P(r);f[z](r)}f.addEventListener?f.addEventListener(r,s,false):f.attachEvent("on"+r,s);var ld=function(){function p(hd){
hd="head";return["<",hd,"></",hd,"><",i,' onl' + 'oad="var d=',g,";d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].",j,"(d.",h,"('script')).",k,"='",l,"//",a.l,"'",'"',"></",i,">"].join("")}var i="body",m=d[i];if(!m){
return setTimeout(ld,100)}a.P(1);var j="appendChild",h="createElement",k="src",n=d[h]("div"),v=n[j](d[h](z)),b=d[h]("iframe"),g="document",e="domain",o;n.style.display="none";m.insertBefore(n,m.firstChild).id=z;b.frameBorder="0";b.id=z+"-loader";if(/MSIE[ ]+6/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
b.src="javascript:false"}b.allowTransparency="true";v[j](b);try{
b.contentWindow[g].open()}catch(w){
c[e]=d[e];o="javascript:var d="+g+".open();d.domain='"+d.domain+"';";b[k]=o+"void(0);"}try{
var t=b.contentWindow[g];t.write(p());t.close()}catch(x){
b[k]=o+'d.write("'+p().replace(/"/g,String.fromCharCode(92)+'"')+'");d.close();'}a.P(2)};ld()};nt()})({
loader: "static.olark.com/jsclient/loader0.js",name:"olark",methods:["configure","extend","declare","identify"]});
/* custom configuration goes here (www.olark.com/documentation) */
olark.identify('');/*]]>*/</script><noscript><a href="https://www.olark.com/site//contact" title="Contact us" target="_blank">Questions? Feedback?</a> powered by <a href="http://www.olark.com?welcome" title="Olark live chat software">Olark live chat software</a></noscript>
<!-- end olark code -->
```

To me, it looks like the javascript is dealing with passing of information back in forth from the chat. However, where is the form itself generated? I don't see any HTML elements or anything for the structure.

Say I have a simple HTML form hosted on my server and I want others to be able to generate this simple form on their site.

```
<form method = "post" id="simpleform">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="textbox" name="simpletext"/></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submittext"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I'm not asking for someone to explicitly write out the code, but in a general sense how would I accomplish this? Would I have to make an html file and then give the link to be included or would I do something like put it in a javascript function and call that from the site?

**edit- It was pointed out to me that using JSONP this can be accomplished. I have found a tutorial [here](http://www.w3resource.com/JSON/JSONP.php) which gives me an idea, but I still have no idea how to generate HTML from this. Say I wanted to make that form which I mentioned, how could I pass HTML elements?**

Comment: JSONP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about

Comment: @jaux I see that it works based on callbacks, but can I pass HTML structure through a callback?

Answer (score 2):

Typically scripts like you mention work like this:

- A user pastes a script, or a `<script>` tag into their site
- The added code will load some more code from the script author's site
- The script that's being loaded will perform the actual work, eg. generating the HTML, loading any CSS files, etc.